# First-order Taylor Series

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

Let F be a differentiable function of space and time.
Apparently, a first-order Taylor expansion of F yields:

$$\delta\,F=F(x+\delta\,x,t+\delta\,t)-F(x,t)=(\delta\,x\nabla)F+(\frac{\partial\,F}{\partial\,t})\delta\,t$$

What do I need to know in order to understand that?
What type of function is $\delta\,F$?

Perhaps someone could tell me how to proceed or where I can find the relevant information.

Comment: the definition of  is given as the difference you have after =, the  is an abbreviation for difference

Comment: @trula, okay, that is the difference between the values of the function arguments at two different positions/times?

Comment: @trula, could I say that it is a multiplication of the infinitesimally small changes of the function arguments by the size of the difference intervals?

Comment: No its just the difference mentioned